# How to add attribute onto a SoapHeader node using php Soap library

Tags: php, soap, attributes, namespaces, soapheader

How to add attributes onto a node in Soap header using php's Soap library ?

Tried all of the examples that are available (both here on StackOverflow, and php.net ( examples, comments, etc .. ).

```
$a = ['_'=> 'bar', 'id' => 1, 'val' => 'foo'];
$x = new SoapVar($a,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
$h = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope','FFS', $x);
```

This results in:

```
    <env:FFS>
        <_>bar</_>
        <id>1</id>
        <val>foo</val>
    </env:FFS>
```

Additional: Attributes should be namespaced. Adding a namespaced node to the body and/or header without attributes isn't a problem. Adding an attribute to the node is a problem.

Resulting node i need to get at the end should look like

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:nsx="http://example.com">
    <env:Header>
        <node nsx:foo="bar">
            <nsx:baz>bam</nsx:baz>
        </node>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        [ snip ]
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**NOTE**: Since all of the examples / tips I've found so far suggest either constructing the node manually or using RAW XML i have to stress the following:

- I don't want to use XSD_ANYXML,
- I don't want to use SimpleXML and/or DOMElement to create a node.
- I'll accept suggestions for other SOAP libraries that will allow me to easily construct a call.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think this is just not possible. You might need to look at some XML libraries for this.

Comment: Yes, from further investigation i have also come to conclusion that this is not possible with built-in libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do itin WSDL mode:

```
class FromSystemId {
    protected $_ = "Bla bla bla";
    protected $ID = "999";
}

class Auth {
/**
 * @var FromSystemId
 */
protected $FromSystemId;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $UserName;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $Password;

/**
 * Auth constructor.
 * @param FromSystemId $FromSystemId
 * @param string $UserName
 * @param string $Password
 */
public function __construct(FromSystemId $FromSystemId, $UserName, $Password)
{
    $this->FromSystemId = $FromSystemId;
    $this->UserName = $UserName;
    $this->Password = $Password;
}
}

try {

$soap = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", [
        "location" => "some soap api url",
        "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,
        "trace" => true,
        "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        "classmap" => [
            "Auth" => "Auth",
            "FromSystemId" => "FromSystemId",
        ]
]);


$auth = new Auth(new FromSystemId(), "user", "password");
$soap->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader("ns", "Auth", $auth));
```

The result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:ns1="aa"
               xmlns:ns2="bb">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:Auth xsi:type="ns1:Auth">
        <ns1:FromSystemId ID="999">Bla bla bla</ns1:FromSystemId>
        <ns1:UserName>user</ns1:UserName>
        <ns1:Password>password</ns1:Password>
    </ns2:Auth>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetCountriesRQ/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the wanted result.

Node should look like <ns2:auth ns1:type="auth"> or something similar.

Comment: Above example doesn't return posted result. `FromSystemId ` will contain 2 tags: `<ID>999</ID>` and `<_>Bla Bla Bla</_>`